# Removing rollover state on mobile?

Tags: html, css, hover

I currently am using HTML/CSS to trigger a rollover state for an image. This rollover state appears when the image is hovered over, but also when adjacent text is rolled over in the parent div.

However, on mobile (site is responsive), clicking/tapping the image enables this rollover state, and a second click/tap is required to get the link to work.

How do I stop this from happening?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="four columns post alpha">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="image">
                <a href="banjee.html"><img class="scale-with-grid" src="images/thumb_banjee.jpg">
                <img class="scale-with-grid hoverimage" src="images/thumb_overlay.png"></a>
                </div>
                <a href="banjee.html"><h3>Banjee</h3></a>


            </div>
```

And here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.hoverimage { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    display: none; 
}

.thumbnail:hover .hoverimage, 
.image:hover .hoverimage { 
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make this css styling conditional when browsing from PC using Javascript code:

```
if(!(/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))){
$(".hoverimage").css({'position':'absolute','top':0,'left':0,'display':'none'});
$(".thumbnail:hover .hoverimage, .image:hover .hoverimage").css({'display':'block','cursor':'pointer'});
}
```